# Unable to use HTML DOM Parser on server

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have a website running on ipage and the main part of my site uses HTML DOM Parser to gather information. I am fully aware the coding works as it runs on XAMPP and many free server hosters. I was wandering if there was a setting the stopped any GET requests from happening.

**Below is the error I get in the console**

Request URL:    http://my-site.com/php/rt-news-proxy.php?page=1

Request Method:     GET

Status Code:    HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

I hope you can help shed some light on this problem and thank you for your time.

Comment: Sounds like a possible permissions error. From Wikipedia: _"A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that the server can be reached and understood the request, but refuses to take any further action. Status code 403 responses are the result of the web server being configured to deny access, for some reason, to the requested resource by the client."_...

Comment: @War10ck I had a feeling that it is but im not sure what could be the case. I looked in .htaccess but nothing was in there that might stop communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my answer again (I forgot I solved this problem before). To fix it in general I had to change a line in the php.ini on the server to fix it. To fix it find the following line **allow_url_fopen = Off** and change it to **On**. To find the php.ini on ipage do the following. When you log in and are directed to the control panel hover on the tab at the top which says **Additional Tools** then click on **CGI and Scripted Language Support**. Next click on **PHP Scripting** and scroll to the bottom where you will find php.ini file and all you have to do is change the value stated.

Hope this Helps :)